How to preserve SwiftData models locally when iClould Sync switch is disabled
I am trying to find a way to preserve data locally when user disable iCloud sync. I am using private database (private container). Lets consider we initialize container like this:
.modelContainer(for: [Note.self])

and a model:
@Model
class Note {
    var id: String?
    var content: String = ""
    var createdAt: Date = Date()
    
    init(id: String, content: String, createdAt: Date) {
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
        self.createdAt = createdAt
        
    }
}

and then we grab a context:
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var context

a at the end we save data:
func createNote() {
        
        let note = Note(id: UUID().uuidString, content: noteText, createdAt: .now)
        context.insert(note)
        try? context.save()
        noteText = ""
    }

Now, this magically works. It creates notes and syncs them across devices that use the same Apple ID. However, is there a way to prevent data loss when iCloud syncing is turned off on one of the devices? Currently, if iCloud syncing is disabled on one device, all data (SwiftData Note models) on that device is erased. Luckily, it doesn't erase data on other devices.
Also what I have noticed, if I continue to add Notes on a device that has iCloud sync disabled, Notes are added locally, and later when I turn on iCloud sync, they are synced to cloud and synced across other devices...
Is there a setting to allow the app to continue working locally when the user turns off iCloud syncing, as if nothing happened? Later, if the user re-enables syncing, can the local data overwrite what's on iCloud?
I know I can watch the status of iCloud account availability changes, but I'm not sure what the proper way to implement something like this would be?

Is this solve? I'm having the same problem.

Hey @Whirlwind, the same problem here, did you solve it?

I found a way to solve this problem but not using pure swiftData. The method is to create two container, one is the container stored locally by swiftData, and the other that created by NSPersistentCloudKitContainer is used to synchronize data to iCloud.
The snippet code as follow:
1. create swiftData container
let config = ModelConfiguration(cloudKitDatabase: .none)
let container = try! ModelContainer(
    for: Group.self, Account.self, Record.self, Tag.self, ChartModel.self,
    configurations: config
)

2. create cloudContainer to sync local data
Task {
let ckContainer = CKContainer(identifier: cloudIdentifier)
let status = try? await ckContainer.accountStatus()
// avoid crash when iCloud account is not available
if status == CKAccountStatus.available {
    let desc = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: config.url)
    let opts = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: cloudIdentifier)
    desc.cloudKitContainerOptions = opts
    desc.shouldAddStoreAsynchronously = false
    if let mom = NSManagedObjectModel.makeManagedObjectModel(for: [Group.self, Account.self, Record.self, Tag.self, ChartModel.self]) {
        cloudContainer = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: cloudContainerName, managedObjectModel: mom)
        cloudContainer!.persistentStoreDescriptions = [desc]
        cloudContainer!.loadPersistentStores { desc, error in
            if let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        try? cloudContainer!.initializeCloudKitSchema()
    }
}

You need notice this case, when a user switchs the account, the local data may be synchronized from one account to another account.
